# How to solve unmet dependencies?

Tags: 13.04, dependencies

I'm trying to install Nitro with this :

```
sudo apt-get install nitro
```

And then I get this :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nitro : Depends: gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve this?

**UPDATE**

The output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list is :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring multiverse main universe restricted #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse main universe restricted #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-security multiverse main universe restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-security universe
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
deb-src http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

and the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* is :

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu raring main
deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/nitro/ubuntu raring main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/nitro/ubuntu raring main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu raring main
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/67943

Comment: Still didn't work, I've updated my question

Comment: `gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0` has been discontinued and is no longer in repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try `sudo apt-get -f install`, then retry getting nitro. If that doesn't work, run `sudo apt-get clean`, then `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Um still didn't work..

Comment: I have updated my question with some info.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but this worked for me:

http://www.noobslab.com/2012/12/nitro-task-manager-for-ubuntu.html

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cooperjona/nitrotasks
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nitrotasks
```

Comment: Is it the same application with Nitro in Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: It is. Nitro 1.5.