# How to create Facebook webapp?

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, webapps, facebook

I'm migrating from Mac to Ubuntu Linux (14.04).

I've read that there are a number of 'web apps' that encapsulate frequent and common web applications into kind-of standalone units known as 'webapps'. I've got the Twitter one sitting in my Unity Launcher right now. It's very handy.

I've seen mentions for a similar Facebook webapp but I can find it nowhere. Intensive googling has served me no good. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

If for some reason it has ceased to exist, how can I create a similar thing? (I'm running Chrome as my default browser. I tried adding Facebook as an app to Chrome and creating a desktop icon, but unfortunately that opens as a window under Chrome and does not give it it's own icon in the Unity Launcher sidebar, as I desire.)

Thanks to anybody who can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow to steps given in this link to download and install Facebook App on ubuntu: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/fb-messenger-and-facebook-applications.html.

After installing the Ubuntu Desktop Facebook Application, you will find it in the Unity dash Applications.

For creating a shortcut on desktop, Go to the folder /usr/share/applications and find the facebook app. Then right click on it and copy. Now open up the Desktop folder. Right click and then select paste.

The facebook app will be on your desktop !!

Comment: It didn’t quite work… after running 
       `sudo apt-get install desktop-facebook`
I get the error
       `The following packages have unmet dependencies: desktop-facebook : Depends on girl.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 but it is not installable`

Comment: Refer these links: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287360/how-to-solve-unmet-dependencies and http://askubuntu.com/questions/453115/vanished-dependency-gir1-2-launchpad-integration-3-0