# Vanished dependency: gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0

Tags: dependencies, 14.04, nitro

I'm trying to install a facebook-webapp but the dependency `gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0` is not found and listed as uninstallable. I have been unable to locate it anywhere except for references to '*Nitro*' (which apparently doesn't work either because of this package missing).

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can work around this? I am running Ubuntu 14.04, fresh install and novice user.

Answer (score 2):

gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 repository support has been discontinued

Though you can install using debian installer

- [gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0_0.1.56_amd64.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/launchpad-integration/gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0_0.1.56_amd64.deb)
- [gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0_0.1.56_i386.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/launchpad-integration/gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0_0.1.56_i386.deb)

It has dependencies which needs to be met that can also be downloaded

**(1)** [liblaunchpad-integration-common](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/launchpad-integration/liblaunchpad-integration-common_0.1.56.1_all.deb)

**(2)** liblaunchpad-integration-3.0

- [64-bit version](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/launchpad-integration/liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1_0.1.56.2_amd64.deb)
- [32-bit version](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/launchpad-integration/liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1_0.1.56.2_i386.deb)

Start from installing **liblaunchpad-integration-common**

```
sudo dpkg -i liblaunchpad-integration-common_0.1.56.1_all.deb
```

Then install **liblaunchpad-integration-3.0**

```
sudo dpkg -i liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1_0.1.56_amd64.deb
```

Finally install **gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0**

```
sudo dpkg -i gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0_0.1.56_amd64.deb
```

Et Volia! you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work: 
`qubex@sputnik:~$ sudo dpkg -i liblaunchpad-integration-common_0.1.56.1_all.deb
dpkg: error processing archive liblaunchpad-integration-common_0.1.56.1_all.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 liblaunchpad-integration-common_0.1.56.1_all.deb
qubex@sputnik:~$`

Comment: `cd` to to Download directory of these packages. if they are saved on Desktop then: do `cd ~/Desktop` first or if they are in Download Folder then `cd ~/Downloads` first. Then apply above three commands sequentially in terminal.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself clearly. They are downloaded to nowhere because they can be downloaded from nowhere. They're nowhere I can find.

Comment: i downloaded from links. http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/launchpad-integration/gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0_0.1.56_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/launchpad-integration/liblaunchpad-integration-common_0.1.56.1_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/launchpad-integration/liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1_0.1.56.2_amd64.deb

Comment: This seems to have gotten Nitro working for me again, though I should mention that I did have to restart the computer before the fix took effect.