# Nitro todo list app doesn't appear to work in Trusty (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, nitro

After a fresh install of 14.04, I tried installing Nitro, but the app doesn't open. The launcher icon jiggles a bit when I click on it, and then stops.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the script here (https://gist.github.com/metasoarous/11328060 - choose 64 or 32 bit depending on your system) and run with `sudo`.

You will have to reboot for the changes to take effect, but after that Nitro should work again.

Comment: Credit goes to Back.Slash's - http://askubuntu.com/questions/453115/vanished-dependency-gir1-2-launchpad-integration-3-0. I created a new question in hopes it would be a little easier for people with problems specific to Nitro to find this answer.