# install software center

Tags: software-installation, software-sources

```
root@localhost:~# apt-get install software-center

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 software-center :

Depends: python-gobject (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: python-gobject-cairo

Depends: python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets but it is not going to be installed

Recommends: gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 but it is not installable

Recommends: sessioninstaller but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: How is it after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`?

Answer (score 0):

What i believe you have broken package may be while your previous attempt to install software center, I suggest you check the following..

`sudo apt-get purge software-center`

then try

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-gobject-cairo python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets sessioninstaller -y
```

As last step

```
 sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: hope by following above you can install software center, in case still you need gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 check this  http://askubuntu.com/questions/453115/vanished-dependency-gir1-2-launchpad-integration-3-0

Comment: it doesn't work